# mysql result with foreach in php 5.2 not working but works in php 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a program which runs beautifully on my local MAMP server (running an updated version of PHP), however when I upload it via FTP to a remote server it crashes. I have isolated the problem to being differences in the PHP versions, since the remote is running PHP 5.2.

```
//Selects ALL from the table 'all_words' which contains two columns: word and  id
$sql = "SELECT word FROM all_words";

//Query the database
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

//Create an array to hold results
$resultArray = array();

//Loop through results and push to end of array
foreach($result as $value){
    array_push($resultArray, $value['word']);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be? I understand that PHP 5.4 added a ton of new features, but I can't seem to find any that would make my code not work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you got any errors? Have you read error logs? How exactly it's not working - blank screen? Unexpected results? Your PC explodes?

Comment: Take a look if the extension php_mysqli.dll is installed

Comment: isnt the mysqli extension deprecated now ! check whether its compatible with your php version, if it is compatible, see if the $dbc variable has to be the second param!

Comment: MySQLI isn't close to deprecation.  MySQL *is* deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can remember, you can't iterate over an object in PHP 5.2; $result is a mysqli object, not an array, hence your error in the older version.

Comment: Thanks, that ended up being the issue. I wrote the program iterating over the object using `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ //Code here... } `